# BottomTabNavigator is half override when built standalone app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm using react-native with expo. My problem is it's work fine when running in expo client. But when I built a standalone app, the bottom tab from `createBottomTabNavigator` of react-navigation is lost a half.

Expo client screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN0QG.png

Standalone app screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/H18o3.png

Here's my navigator code

MainTabNavigator.js

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    Transactions: TransactionsStack,
    Profile: ProfileStack,
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'Home'
    });

export default tabNavigator;
```

AppNavigator.js

```
export default createAppContainer(
    createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
        Auth: AuthNavigator,
        Main: MainTabNavigator
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
        transition: (
            <Transition.Together>
                <Transition.Out
                    type="slide-bottom"
                    durationMs={400}
                    interpolation="easeIn"
                />
                <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={500} />
            </Transition.Together>
        )
    })
);
```

I don't know if there's something wrong with my code or error in the expo standalone app bundler. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted an issue in Expo's Github repository and have an answer. The problem is I'm using the `androidStatusBar` prop in app.json file. When compiling to standalone, it pushes my status bar down below, therefore, it's lost a half. The solution is simply to remove it and make use of the `<StatusBar/>` of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done it yet, my advice is to start a project with `react-native init`, link all dependencies and just c/p source code you wrote. Everything should be fine then. Just don't use `eject` from Expo.

Comment: So maybe the problem is because of the expo standalone bundler right? I'm new to react-native, working with pure react-native I have to do lots of configuration in Gradle, etc ... expo makes it a lot easier for me. So maybe your suggestion isn't fit for me. Anyway, thank for your help.